# CMake, generated dependencies, and Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I have a project which involves generating header files from data. There are going to be a lot of these, so I'd like a way to do this that's extensible.

I have a solution which works on Linux and OS X (both Makefiles and XCode) but doesn't work on Visual Studio. The header files are always regenerated on Visual Studio no matter what.

Here's a cut-down example to illustrate what I mean. Sorry about the code dump, but this is the smallest I could make it.

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
project(the_project)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

SET(GEN_INCLUDES_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated_includes")
FILE(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${GEN_INCLUDES_DIR})

# Generator
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(header_generator PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(header_generator
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/generator.c
)

# Symbolic target for all generated includes
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(GeneratedIncludes)
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(GeneratedIncludes PROPERTIES SYMBOLIC TRUE)

# Macro for generating a single header
macro(GenerateHeader tag input_file target_header)
    SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(Generate${tag} PROPERTIES SYMBOLIC TRUE)
    SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(${target_header} PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)
    ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(Generate${tag} DEPENDS ${GEN_INCLUDES_DIR}/${target_header})
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
        OUTPUT ${GEN_INCLUDES_DIR}/${target_header}
        COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:header_generator>
        ARGS ${input_file} ${target_header}
          DEPENDS header_generator ${input_file}
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${GEN_INCLUDES_DIR}
        COMMENT "Generating ${target_header}"
    )
    ADD_DEPENDENCIES(GeneratedIncludes Generate${tag})
    INSTALL(FILES "${GEN_INCLUDES_DIR}/${target_header}" DESTINATION include)
endmacro()

# The headers to generate
GenerateHeader(File1 input1.txt generated1.h)
GenerateHeader(File2 input2.txt generated2.h)

# A real target
ADD_EXECUTABLE(product main.c)
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(product GeneratedIncludes)
TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(product PRIVATE ${GEN_INCLUDES_DIR})
```

`generator.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE* out = fopen(argv[2], "wt");
    fprintf(out, "/* Pretend we used the file %s somehow */\n", argv[1]);
    fclose(out);
}
```

`main.c`:

```
#include "generated1.h"
#include "generated2.h"

int main() { return 0; }
```

You also need two data files, called `input1.txt` and `input2.txt`. They can be empty. You can verify that on OS X or Linux, this does not rebuild the header files unless you touch the generator source code or one of the data files. On Visual Studio, it rebuilds them every time.

I turned on "Diagnostic" level output for MSBuild, and this is the part of the output that seems to be the problem:

```
3>------ Up-To-Date check: Project: GenerateFile1.vcxproj, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
3>Project not up to date because the following 0 build outputs were missing:
3> up to date is missing: 'C:\BLAH\CMAKE_EXAMPLE_BUILD\CMAKEFILES\GENERATEFILE1'
3>
3>------ Build started: Project: GenerateFile1, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
4>------ Up-To-Date check: Project: GenerateFile2.vcxproj, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
4>Project not up to date because the following 0 build outputs were missing:
4> up to date is missing: 'C:\BLAH\CMAKE_EXAMPLE_BUILD\CMAKEFILES\GENERATEFILE2'
4>
4>------ Build started: Project: GenerateFile2, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
```

If I'm reading that correctly, MSBuild appears to be looking for a file which isn't being generated.

Any ideas?

Software versions: CMake 3.10.2, Visual Studio 15 2017

Comment: Command `SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES` is applicable for **files**. Why do you use it for **targets** (`header_generator`, `GeneratedIncludes`,  `Generate${tag}`)?

Comment: Because I don't necessarily know any better. So what does SYMBOLIC actually mean? My intuition may be incorrect for this.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_sf/SYMBOLIC.html), *SYMBOLIC* is used for some sort of pseudo files. I see no reason to use it in you case. BTW, according to build log, Visual Studio tends to rebuild exactly these files (marked with *SYMBOLIC*).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Removing those lines works on POSIX-ish platforms and I will try it on Visual Studio later today. If you write this up as an answer, I'll give you the tick, because I think you got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to build log, MSBuild looks for a files `CMAKEFILES\GENERATEFILE1` and `CMAKEFILES\GENERATEFILE2` which are listed in your `CMakeLists.txt` as **targets**, not as a *files*. Most likely, such file's dependencies are generate because of call

```
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(Generate${tag} PROPERTIES SYMBOLIC TRUE)
```

but I see no reason in this call.

And the call by itself is wrong: a command `SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES` should be used only on *files*, not a *targets*.

---

Also, there is no need in setting *GENERATED* property of files in your code:
CMake automatically set this property on files listed in *OUTPUT* option of `add_custom_command` in the same `CMakeLists.txt` which depends on these files. And this is exactly your case.